# No HDMI option in sound settings

Tags: sound, 16.04, hdmi, xps

When I connect my TV via HDMI to my laptop, sound is outputted from laptop instead of TV. When I go to sound settings, I don't see HDMI option. There are only two options (see image):

[image]

I tried installin ALSA daily (https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/), reinstalling pulseaudio entirely, then doing `pulseuadio -k` while hdmi connected, also enabled nvidia drivers to be used (if that would help with sound?). Nothing helps.

P.S. Why sound management in ubuntu has to be this messy?